# Python not work Delete mysql

Tags: python, mysql

**I made program is input and delete data in MYSQL but program cant delete or if problem should be .... help me pls**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="l",user="r",passwd="9",db="t")
cursor = conn.cursor()

try:
        num0 = raw_input("Select Row : ")
        num1 = int(input("Number row 1-10 : "))

        if num1 <= 10:
                sqlde0 = "DELETE FROM '%s' WHERE user1 = '%d' " %(num0,num1)
                cursor.execute(sqlde0, (num1))
                conn.commit()
                print "Delete sucess"

except:
        conn.rollback()
        print "Delete False"
        print "Rollback Data"

conn.close()
```

result :

```
Select Row : dt
Number row 1-10 : 1
Delete False
Rollback Data
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your try-except first then change the 'DELETE' to 'select' for now. so we can see the errors